# Clear search filter shortcut in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear the search filter in Unity editor? It's really tedious to precisely click on the tiny (X) everytime I do a search.

[image: unity search box]

Answer (score 1):

In 2019.1 you can press [ESC] I just found out.

Comment: I am using 2018 LTS, so looks like I would have to wait :(

Comment: Works in 2018.3.14 too. So I guess 2018LTS should do it too?

Comment: The field should have focus by the way. So if you pressed enter, you should select it again and press escape.